# How to use browser to get authorization and return back to client for native iOS?

Tags: ios, cordova, authentication, ionic-framework

I have a mobile app built in Ionic, and am using Azure B2C to authenticate clients.  It requires I navigate out to get use sign-in, and then retrieve a token in response.  The trouble seems to be how to return back to my app while parsing the token.

What I am doing is using either window.open or InAppBrowser, like:

```
ref = window.open(url, '_self', 'location=no, toolbar=yes');
```

response location url:

```
localhost:8080/#access_token=<my_access_token>&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&id_token=<my_id_token>
```

> In Xcode iPhone simulator, Safari reports:  Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server.

Let's say I have this logic:

```
var standalone = window.navigator.standalone,
    userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(),
    safari = /safari/.test( userAgent ),
    ios = /iphone|ipod|ipad/.test( userAgent );

if( ios ) {
    if ( !standalone && safari ) {
        //browser
    } else if ( standalone && !safari ) {
        //standalone
    } else if ( !standalone && !safari ) {
        //uiwebview
    };
} else {
    //not iOS
};
```

I believe I need to use window.open for cases of browser?  And in case of standalone/native I would use InAppBrowser?

I am looking for some good example of how to manage getting token back from browser to either a web or native ios and android app.

> I started thinking that deeplinking might be the way I need to get back to my native app.

FWIW:  My config at the Azure end offers a native options with Redirect URI of either `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` or `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/oauth2/nativeclient`

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can't use a http response url.  You need to create a url scheme for your app and use that so that the token can be returned via your appdelegate

Comment: Thanks.  Would you be able to provide a link to some good examples/writeups of this?